# Concatenate two columns of strings

Tags: awk

How to concatenate two columns of strings and insert _ between them, please?

I have a file:

```
L  o     45
OK kklkj 5
```

The desired result is:

```
L_o      45
OK_kklkj 5
```

I tried:

```
awk '{printf "%12s %22.2f\n", $1+'_'+$2, $3}' file
```

which converts strings to numbers. Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with `sed 's/  */_/'` (if columns are tab separated, simply adapt)?

Comment: The space between the `L_o` and `45` in your output has grown by one space compared to the space between `o` and `45` in the input.  Is that a typo, or due to a tab character? If it's a tab, is there also a tab between the first two fields in the input and should only tabs (not spaces) be accounted for as field delimiters?

Comment: Suppose you remove the two `+` characters and change the embedded single quotes to double quotes around the underscore. In that case, you get something that _works_ but that does not at all produce what you say you want, primarily due to the elaborate `printf` formatting. It is unclear whether the `printf` format string that you use describes what you _actually_ want or whether you want what you say you want, which is different.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this should do([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295823/how-to-merge-join-concatenate-the-first-two-columns-in-a-text-file-separated-b)):

```
awk '{$1=(NR==1?"ID":$1"_"$2); $2=""}1' file
```

there will be extra white space, which can be normalized afterward if needed.

Comment: Why do you insert the string `ID` in the first column of the first line?

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```bash
sed 's/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/_/' file
```

This replaces the first occurrence of one or more consecutive blanks (spaces or tabs) with a single underscore character.

With GNU `sed`, this could be shortened into

```bash
gsed -E 's/\s+/_/' file
```

This does the same as the above for the given data, but would match a larger collection of space-like characters in-between the first two fields if there are such characters there (the `\s` PCRE symbol matches like `[[:space:]]`, which also includes vertical tabs, carriage-returns, and form-feed characters).

Given the data in the question, this produces the following output:

```
L_o     45
OK_kklkj 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{$0=$1"_"$2FS$NF}1' input_file | column -t
L_o       45
OK_kklkj  5
```